# How to set location access for local html file in chrome

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, javascript, geolocation

So i've built my own startpage and I'm using a weather API to display the local weather. Needless to say I don't want to give chrome explicit access to my location everytime i open a tab since I coded it myself. I found [this](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3123708) tutorial from google but the "add" option is not present for me in the locations tab.

Has anyone got an idea how to do this? Right now for every window/tab I open I have to click the allow button for location access.

Comment: Looks like the Add option only applies to certain content types. What about setting location to Block by default, then explicitly allow when you need the browser to access your location?

Comment: I do block by default. The thing is that I'd like to make an exception for only the page which I've coded myself because I use it as a start page and it uses a weather API to display the local weather. However, it's not usable if I have to accept location with every tab I open.